# Tizen Samsung SDK: How do you play HLS video?

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, tizen, http-live-streaming

http://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenGuide/?FolderName=tizen61&FileName=index.html#/TizenGuide/?Foldername=tizen61&Filename=index.html

The above says:

> You have two options for multimedia player in Tizen application.
>
> ■Use  HTML5  tag. It doesn’t support DRMs and streaming engines like  DASH, HAS, HLS and SmoothStreaming.
>
> ■Use avplay API or Samsung TV
>    product API. It supports DRMs and streaming engines like DASH, HAS,
>    HLS and SmoothStreaming.

Is this true?  They say it's a private SDK, is that why I can't see any references to it online?  And do we need the private sdk to stream HLS at all, or is it only for fancy player stuff?

Comment: Video tag on other platforms plays HLS fine. You need to check it on actual device.

Comment: Right, I know the video tag normally can play HLS.  But it varies by browser.  And the Tizen Samsung documentation says that it's browser doesn't do HLS.    And I don't even know if any actual TVs are out yet, just the emulator... In the emulator, at least, I know that the video tag doesn't seem to work with HLS (but does regular video).

Comment: FYI, i remember it works to play hls on emulator using video tag. But it doesn't work on the real TV i had.
And only avplayer can play hls on real device....

Comment: The emulator I had access to in February definitely couldn't play HLS via the video tag.  Did you have a straight up regular Tizen emulator, not the Samsung? Or maybe I had an out of date one.... Either way I had to abandon the Tizen platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML5 video tag does not supports HLS on Tizen platform.

You need to use [AVPlay API](https://github.com/SamsungDForum/PlayerAVPlay) to play streaming or DRM content.

Try to test [AVPlay (Video Play) Sample](http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/api-references/samsung-product-api-references/avplay-api/) in your emulator.

Answer (score 0):

config.xml must content:

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
```

in head html file include:

JS:

```
var init = function () {
    console.log('init() called');
    var videos = document.querySelector('video');
   videos[0].play();
};

window.onload = init;
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <video src="file.m3u8" controls></video>
</body>
```

See also this example: https://github.com/SamsungDForum/PlayerHTML5